# convert float negative value to positive

Tags: java

How to convert float negative value to float positive value

example -1.5 to 1.5

Answer (score 31):

Multiply it by -1.

Or negate it.

Or get the absolute value.

Basic arithmetics.

```
float neg = -1.5f;
float pos1 = neg * -1;
float pos2 = -neg;
float pos3 = Math.abs(neg);
```

Comment: or use Math.abs() in case you dont know if your number is positive or negative but you want it to be positive.

Comment: @Jones: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Be sure you accept the answer you like best by clicking the check-box next to it.

Answer (score 3):

assign the negative:

```
float f = -1.5f;
f = -f;
```

Answer (score 3):

The *Absolute Value Function* in Java is **Math.abs**:

```
double f = Math.abs(-1.5); // f is now 1.5
```

Comment: The example uses float and not double.

Answer (score 0):

The `abs` function:

```
float f = -90;    
System.out.println(Math.abs(f));
```

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Answer (score 0):

If you know that it is negative - just multiply -1f:

```
float example = -1.5f;
example *= -1f;
```

Also you can use Math.abs:

```
example = (float)Math.abs(example);
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting from positive or vice versa is simple by prepending - sign.

`float var = -1.5;
var = -var;`